Foundry tests fail with `[NotActivated] EvmError: NotActivated` while fork test
The fork tests works perfectly well with Hardhat.
But when I tried with Foundry using different evm_version in foundry.toml file and also tried compiling with different versions solc = "0.8.18" but still getting the same EvmError: NotActivated error
    │   │   │   │   ├─ [8391762413094784964] 0x4b93d0EC9Ae9C60A71A292921B2a0162E140510d::synthTotalSupply(0x7345544800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) [staticcall]
│   │   │   │   │   ├─ [8391762413094777769] 0xA90ed62a10Fd1CecdaDB7F3Ca20ECB63Cf32f841::synthTotalSupply(0x7345544800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) [delegatecall]
│   │   │   │   │   │   └─ ← [NotActivated] EvmError: NotActivated
│   │   │   │   │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert

How do I resolve it?

This is likely happening because you did not set your evm_version in your foundry.toml. Update the evm_version in your foundry.toml as shown below and it should fix it.
[profile.default]
 evm_version = 'shanghai'

